# Proof verification : Closure of the graph of $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ is not a path connected set.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be defined on $(0,1)$ and $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$.

$S$ is the graph of $f$, and $\bar S = S \cup (\{0 \} \times [-1,1])$. Show that $\bar S$ is not a path connected set.

Proof. Let $x \in \{0 \} \times [-1,1]$, and $y \in S$. Suppose there exists a function $\alpha : [0,1] \to \bar S$ such that $\alpha(0) = x, \alpha(1) =y$. Define $t_0 = \sup\{t \in [0,1] : \alpha(t) \in \{ 0 \} \times [-1,1] \}$.

Then, $\alpha([t_0,1])$ contains at most one point of $\{ 0 \} \times [-1,1]$.

However, $\overline {\alpha([t_0,1])}$ contains all point of $\{ 0 \} \times [-1,1]$. (Am I right? I can't come up with rigorous proof.)

This means $\alpha([t_0,1])$ is not a closed set, and therefore not a compact set. But, as $[t_0,1]$ is compact, $\alpha$ is not continuous on $t_0$.

I know there are good answers for this question, but as I know, there is no post using this method, so I uploaded this. Is my proof right? Is there anyway to make the proof better while using definition of $t_0$ and showing that $\alpha$ is not continuous on $t_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the missing part: the projection $p$ on the $x$ axis is continuous, since we live inside the $xy$-plane. Then $p\circ\alpha$ is continuous, and $p(\alpha([t_0,1]))$ is connected and contains $0=p(\alpha(t_0))$ and $s=p(\alpha(1))\ne0$. Thus $\alpha([t_0,1])$ contains the whole piece of $S$ between $0$ and $s$, whose closure contains $\{0\}\times[-1,1]$.

The rest seems to be correct.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you.